# ubantu mysql8 installation using script with UI

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I am trying to automate the mysql-server installation. I searched online and could not get any suggestions.
Issue I am seeing in Ubantu 18.04 is that its all not command prompt. Its going to a UI.
how can I install on all the hosts with a shell script.

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

I tried `echo " y 0 password password y y y y y y"| sudo mysql_secure_installation`

still its not working. any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Installing MySQL

```
cd /tmp/
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb 
rm mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb 
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server -y
```

Using MySQL

```
mysql_secure_installation
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE {datbase_name};
CREATE USER `{database_user}`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY '{database_password}';
GRANT ALL ON {datbase_name}.* TO `{database_user}`@`localhost`;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Comment: its still going to UI. is there a way I can avoid that

Comment: I do not want any user interaction even for password. I am thinking of keeping them in note pad